# How to compile C code from other directories in Terminal?

Tags: c, terminal

I am trying to figure out how to compile in Terminal when the project is organized like this:

```
 ▼ Practice Exercises
   ▼ example_problems_c
       example_problems_ch1.c
       example_problems_ch2.c
       example_problems_ch3.c
       example_problems_ch4.c

   ▼ example_problems_h
       example_problems_ch1.h
       example_problems_ch2.h
       example_problems_ch3.h
       example_problems_ch4.h

   ▼ example_util_c
       example_conversions.c
       example_lines.c
       example_searches.c

   ▼ example_util_h
       example_conversions.h
       example_lines.h
       example_searches.h

    example_main.c
```

Does anyone have solutions to this?

Comment: Terminal? As in Linux? If it's Linux, you could use a `make` file to cook your recipe for building according to this directory structure. See make reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: That doesn't look like a single project. Instead it looks like a number of separate sources and headers for different chapters or exercises. Do you need to compile them one at a time or all at once. And if all at once into what? `example_main.c`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cc -Iexample_problems_h -Iexample_util_h example_problems_c/*.c example_util_c/*.c example_main.c -o name_of_example
```

Possibly you will need to add other libraries for linking if it complains but since I don't know what's in the source code I can't give you that.

Also, this solution assumes that you only have one `main` function, presumably in `example_main.c` and no other duplicate function names.